# Disable column resizing after filtering in p:dataTable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a Primefaces datatable that in default case is 100% of parent.
I can filter column using some checkbox, using property rendered on column I can hide it when checkbox is selected.

Now I want datatable columns not grow when I hide a column, in this case I don't want datatable to fit parent size. But it's width must reduce.

Comment: Give all columns an explicit size

Comment: I don't want to use fixed width using px value, percentage is possible ?

Comment: I have no idea how things behave if you you say total width should be 100% but individual colums do not accumulate to 100%.... Try...

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough, when all columns are displayed I want table 100% of parent, i.e. it must cover all parent div width, but if I hide some column, table size must reduce width. Dims of column must be constant. I've tried to set style:width at all columns and columngroup for header, but nothing is changed.

Comment: I've tried to set width attribute of p:datatable too, same behavior.

Comment: Try with a plain html table in a div.... Hide one column with css (display:none) and try to get it working in plain html. If you have that solution, you have the PrimeFaces one as well (at least most likely)